# countdown timer instead of count up

Tags: android

I'm at the start of writing a countdown timer for a football match. The code below increments 1 second at a time to 30mins. How can I count down instead of counting up;

```
//Countdown clock button
    Button counterBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
    counterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new CountDownTimer(1800000, 1000){
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                    Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
                    counterBtn.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    counter++;
                }
                public  void onFinish(){
                    Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
                    counterBtn.setText("FULL TIME");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

As the CountDownTimer has millisInFuture which seems to start the end time I'm confused how this can count down instead of count up.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `millisUntilFinished` represents the number of milliseconds in the future from the call to `start()` until the countdown is done and `onFinish()` is called. It makes more sense that you use this as the actual value to display the remaining time instead of using a `counter`.

Taking this into consideration, the `onTick()` method can be modified as below to display a countdown --

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
    Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
    counterBtn.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
counter--;
```

what you are looking for?

Comment: I'd made the mistake as I'm new to Android / Java dev, and i just assumed you incremented, I've posted below some code I've worked on since that fixes the problem and is alot easy to read

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out;

```
    Button counterBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
    counterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new CountDownTimer(70000, 1000){
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                    long l = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                    int i = (int) l;
                    Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
                    counterBtn.setText(secondsToString(i));
                }
                public  void onFinish(){
                    Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
                    counterBtn.setText("FULL TIME");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

And the method I used for formatting was;

```
private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", pTime / 60, pTime % 60);
}
```